# Android Studio - Error while creating Table - Logcat

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, logcat

### DatabaseHelperClass.java

This is the database helper class for creating the database in android. But it is not working as I see in the android logcat. It is unable to point location column in database. Please advise if I made any mistake in the below mention classes.

```
public class DatabaseHelperClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "metrolines.db";

    public DatabaseHelperClass(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        /* CREATE CLASS */
        db.execSQL(Station.CREATE_TABLE);

        Log.d("Create Table", "Passed this step");
        Insert_Station(new Station("Uttam Nagar East","West Delhi"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        /* DROP TABLE IF EXIST */
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Station.TABLE_NAME);

        /* CREATE TABLES AGAIN */
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void Insert_Station(Station station) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Station.STATION_NAME, station.getD_Station());
        contentValues.put(Station.STATION_LOCATION, station.getD_Location());

        db.insert(Station.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        db.close();
    }

    public List<Station> getStationList() {
        List<Station> stationList = new ArrayList<Station>();

        //StationList
        String SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM " + Station.TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT_QUERY, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Station station = new Station();
                station.setD_Station(cursor.getString(1));
                station.setD_Location(cursor.getString(2));
                stationList.add(station);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return stationList;
    }}
```

### Station.java

```
public class Station {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "STATION_TABLE";

    public static final String STATION_NAME = "Station_name" ;
    public static final String STATION_LOCATION = "Location_name" ;

    private String D_Station;
    private String D_Location;

    //create table SQL Query
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE STATION_TABLE (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Station_name TEXT, Location_name TEXT)";

    public Station(){

    }

    public Station(String d_Station, String d_Location) {
        D_Station = d_Station;
        D_Location = d_Location;
    }

    public String getD_Station() {
        return D_Station;
    }

    public void setD_Station(String d_Station) {
        D_Station = d_Station;
    }

    public String getD_Location() {
        return D_Location;
    }

    public void setD_Location(String d_Location) {
        D_Location = d_Location;
    }
}
```

### MainActiviy.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DatabaseHelperClass db = new DatabaseHelperClass(this);

        Log.d("Insert", "Inserting");
        db.Insert_Station(new Station("Uttam Nagar East", "West Delhi"));
        db.Insert_Station(new Station("Dwarka Sec 9", "West Delhi"));
        db.Insert_Station(new Station("Rajiv Chowk", "Central Delhi"));
        db.Insert_Station(new Station("Hauz Khas", "South Delhi"));
```

### Logcat

```
2020-03-20 09:51:54.330 29987-29987/com.gauravbhagat.meg D/Insert: Inserting
2020-03-20 09:51:54.389 29987-29987/com.gauravbhagat.meg E/SQLiteLog: (1) table STATION_TABLE has no column named Location_name
2020-03-20 09:51:54.436 29987-29987/com.gauravbhagat.meg E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Location_name=West Delhi Station_name=Uttam Nagar East
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table STATION_TABLE has no column named Location_name (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: INSERT INTO STATION_TABLE(Location_name,Station_name) VALUES (?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1229)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:703)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:2019)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1890)
        at com.gauravbhagat.meg.SQliteDataBase.DatabaseHelperClass.Insert_Station(DatabaseHelperClass.java:48)
        at com.gauravbhagat.meg.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7340)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7331)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3269)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1960)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7094)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

Comment: try printing your query in logcat and see if it is correct

Comment: Thanks I get this sorted.